# Why is $\mid e^{2 \pi ixh}-1\mid = 2 \mid sin(\pi xh)\mid $?

Tags: trigonometry

I cant prove or see why this is true ;

$\mid e^{2 \pi ixh}-1\mid = 2 \mid sin(\pi xh)\mid $

help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Take $e^{\pi ixh}$ common and use

a) $\sin(u) = \frac{e^{iu}-e^{-iu}}{2i}$

b)$|e^{iu}|=1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$|e^{2\pi ixh}-1| = |e^{\pi ixh}||e^{\pi ixh} - e^{-\pi ixh}|.$$